# Bootstrap4 treeview with url's

Tags: url, bootstrap-4, treeview

I trying to create a collapsable/expandable treeview in Bootstrap4. There are many examples of this but I haven't been able to get any to work as needed. The problem is that none of them, that I could find, have a url for the text in the tree. As soon as I add a link, the tree no longer functions properly. I found the one described on [this page](https://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2018/03/dynamic-treeview-menu-php-mysql-ajax.html) that comes closest. The code I am using is in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/5hsg1c8L/). This has been edited. See my comment below the code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Treeview Example</title>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div id="myTree"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var treeData = [
                {
                    text: '<a href="google.com">Google</a>',
                    nodes: [
                        {
                            text: "Child-Item-1",
                            nodes: [
                                {
                                    text: "Grandchild-Item-1"
                                },
                                {
                                    text: "Grandchild-Item-2"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            text: "Child-Item-2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    text: "Parent-Item-2"
                },
                {
                    text: "Parent-Item-3"
                },
                {
                    text: "Parent-Item-4"
                },
                {
                    text: "Parent-Item-5"
                }
            ];
            $('#myTree').treeview({
                data: treeData
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>            
        $tmp_data[$v['id']] = &$v;   
    }
```

I have changed by example to non-php so that the problem can be seen. Here is the new [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/5hsg1c8L/4/). As you can see, the collapse/expand work fine but if you click on the google link, nothing happens. Can anyone see a way to get this to work or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put urls , you need to add an "href" attribute in your *treeData* array , like this (Make sure enableLinks is true):

```js
var treeData = [
                {
                    text: 'Google',
                    href: 'https://www.google.com',
                    nodes: [
                        {
                            text: "Child-Item-1",
                            nodes: [
                                {
                                    text: "Grandchild-Item-1",
                                    href: 'https://www.google.com',
                                },
                                {
                                    text: "Grandchild-Item-2",
                                    href: 'https://www.google.com',
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            text: "Child-Item-2",
                            href: 'https://www.google.com',
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    text: "Parent-Item-2",
                    href: 'https://www.google.com',
                },
                {
                    text: "Parent-Item-3",
                    href: 'https://www.google.com',
                },
                {
                    text: "Parent-Item-4",
                    href: 'https://www.google.com',
                },
                {
                    text: "Parent-Item-5",
                    href: 'https://www.google.com',
                }
            ];

        $('#default-tree').treeview({
            data: treeData,
            // expanded to 2 levels
            levels: 2,

            // custom icons
            expandIcon: 'glyph-arrow-down-bold',
            collapseIcon: 'glyph-arrow-up-bold',
            emptyIcon: 'glyphicon',
            nodeIcon: '',
            selectedIcon: '',
            checkedIcon: 'glyph-check',
            uncheckedIcon: '',

            // colors
            color: 'blue', // '#000000',
            backColor: undefined, // '#FFFFFF',
            borderColor: undefined, // '#dddddd',
            onhoverColor: '#F5F5F5',
            selectedColor: '#FFFFFF',
            selectedBackColor: '#428bca',
            searchResultColor: '#D9534F',
            searchResultBackColor: undefined, //'#FFFFFF',

            // enables links
            enableLinks: true,

            // highlights selected items
            highlightSelected: true,

            // highlights search results
            highlightSearchResults: true,

            // shows borders
            showBorder: true,

            // shows icons
            showIcon: true,

            // shows checkboxes
            showCheckbox: true,

            // shows tags
            showTags: false,

            // enables multi select
            multiSelect: false
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.css"></script>


<div id="default-tree"></div>
```